# Is there a function to detect a date format from many possible formats and convert it to a <date> element?

Tags: r, date, shiny

I have a column with a date and the format changes depending on the user's system time settings. For example it could be `ymd:hms` (e.g., 23/12/31 13:56:45) OR `mdy:hms` (e.g., 12/31/23 13:56:45).

I need to identify the correct date format to convert the column to a date element to perform operations on. The data is user-submitted via Shiny, and the application processes the data and allows the user to download processed data. There is no opportunity for me to inspect the data, as I could easily determine the correct format myself.

All of the data is newer than 2018; therefore, if a month is parsed as year (e.g., 04 -> 2004), it's easy to tell that this is incorrect.

I wonder if there is any way to detect the correct format, and apply a function based on the right format? I have searched Stack but could not find any real solution to this problem that didn't involve knowing the correct format of the date.

```
 mutate(`End Time_test` = as_datetime(`End Time_test`),
               `Start Time_test` = as_datetime(`Start Time_test`),
               `Run Time (Min)` = (`End Time_test` - `Start Time_test`)/60) %>% 
          relocate(`Run Time (Min)`, .after = `End Time_test`)
```

CORRECT:

```
Start Time          End Time            Run Time (Min)
2021-08-11 10:04:09 2021-08-11 10:50:46 46.6166666666667
```

WRONG:

```
Start Time          End Time            Run Time (Min)
2005-02-23 13:40:59 2005-02-23 14:57:00 1.26694444444444
```

Comment: Have you checked out `anytime::anytime`? You may need to adjust the year format but that should be easy to detect since it has to be > 18.

Comment: I have not - but it looks promising. Checking it out now, thanks!

Comment: Sure `anytime::anytime("2023/12/31 13:56:45")` will return the same thing as `anytime::anytime("12/31/2023 13:56:45")`. Again, note the YY -> YYYY format change.

Comment: Not sure if that will work, since year is exported by the testing device as YY.

Comment: The following code completely removes the time columns! Weird! `mutate(`End Time_test` = anytime::anytime(`End Time_test`),
                 `Start Time_test` = anytime::anytime(`Start Time_test`))`

Comment: It could be that it is making them `NA` if it does not recognize the format.

Comment: But wouldn't the column be preserved, and it would just say NA?

Comment: Do you need the time component?

Comment: Yes, that’s the most important part since everything revolves around the run time

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- c("12/31/23 13:56:45", "23/31/12 13:56:45")

library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(x, orders = c("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S", "%y/%d/%m %H:%M:%S"))
[1] "2023-12-31 13:56:45 UTC" "2023-12-31 13:56:45 UTC"
```

If you need something more exhaustive you can try `guess_formats` which will return matched formats that you can then use to parse the dates.

Comment: Would this work if all the times in one data frame are one, and times in another data frame are different? The input will always be the same for the data, but differ between files. Will try this when home!

Comment: Yes, if it matches either of the two formats that I have specified it will work. If you have more date formats than this you should use `guess_formats`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I need. Will test when I’m home! Thank you